# iOS custom UITableViewCell hide overflow on top corner

Tags: ios, uitableview, custom-controls

I'm trying to create a custom table view cell that has a button on the right hand side, such that I can click that button and do something different than when I click the regular cell. The problem right now is that on the top cell, where the cell should be rounded, the button is not getting cut off (see picture). I've heard of the view.clipsToBounds property, but I guess I'm not entirely sure how to go about implementing in my custom UITableViewCell class. Thanks for the help!

[image: Screwed Up Table Cell]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a image as background, the image must have the right-high corner rounded. Then use the follow code:

```
UIImage *corner = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"/path/to/image"]; //Or imageNamed:@"image"
purpleButton1.setBackgroundImage:corner forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

That should work.

Comment: Yeah I was hoping to avoid having to do this. From what it looks like though, the view that actually has the rounded corners applied isn't the `UITableViewCell`, but some internal view that houses the entire section of cells. I just created a top, middle, and bottom image set and changed them based on the current `indexPath` value.

Comment: You should also try with cell.layer. Maybe there is a value for the right-high corner ;)